# webview doesn't resize when keypad opens in unity android

Tags: javascript, android, unity-game-engine, webview

The height of viewport is not resized when keypad opens in Unity webview in android.

I think it's a problem of unity webview browser. It doesn't fire resize event whereas IOS webview browser does it.

Because webview doesn't resize. I can't use [VisualViewport javascrupt API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/VisualViewport).

Unity and javascript both can't listen keypad event. (can't use javascript focus event due to the situation that user close keypad by close key in keypad )

Is there any way I could listen keypad open and close event or solve this issue?

Thanks a lot!